# Devuelve NULO en este método

Tags: java, revisión-de-código, map

En este método al probarlo me dice que se pasa valor nulo , la descripción de dicho método es que la clave del map es un String de los profesores y un conjunto ordenado de Tutorías como valor , el cuál creo un método auxiliar para no tener dos bucles anidados.Por tanto a cada profesor se le añade un conjunto de Tutorías si contiene la clave. Me gustaría saber si ven algún defecto en el código como para que pase valor nulo .

```
public SortedMap<String, SortedSet<Tutoria>> getTutoriasPorProfesor() {
   SortedMap<String,SortedSet<Tutoria>> map = new TreeMap<>();
   for(Profesor p:profesores){
      añadeTutoria(p,map);
   }
   return map;
}

private void añadeTutoria(Profesor p, SortedMap<String, SortedSet<Tutoria>> map) {
    for(Tutoria t:p.getTutorias()){
        String clave = p.toString();
    //  SortedSet<Tutoria> valor = p.getTutorias();
        if(map.containsKey(clave)){
           SortedSet<Tutoria> valor = map.get(clave);
           valor.add(t);
           map.put(clave, valor);
    //     map.get(clave).add(t);
    //     map.put(clave, map.get(clave));
        } else {
            SortedSet<Tutoria> aux = new TreeSet<>();
            aux.add(t);
            map.put(clave,aux);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, trata de formatear el código correctamente (por tu bien y el nuestro) cualquier IDE lo hace automáticamente.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea que emite el error que reportas? ¿Dónde estás definiendo `profesores`? ¿Qué valores tiene en la prueba que estás realizando?

Answer (score 1):

Si es que la estructura de profesores es de tipo *List* se podría agregar objetos nulos. 
Ej:

```
java.util.List<Profesor> profesores = new ArrayList<>();
profesores.add(new Profesor("Juan", aux));
profesores.add(null);
```

Al realizar *p.getTutorias()* tendrías un **java.lang.NullPointerException**.

Answer (score 0):

¿No tendrías que darle Get al atributo clave del objeto "p" de tipo Profesor?, es decir, `p.getClave().toString()`, (a menos que la clave de por sí sea un String ya), tal vez por allí vaya el problema. En lo personal lo que veo es que estas convirtiendo todo el objeto "p" a String. Disculpas si me equivoco.

Comment: No , no estoy convirtiendo todo el objeto a String. La clave es el string de los profesores por tanto siempre va a ser la misma , hay que comprobar el valor que es el conjunto ordenado de tutorias , si ya existe o no

Comment: Había leído mal la respuesta , sí, el objeto "p" lo convierto todo a cadena

Comment: claro, pero a lo que voy es, si tienes un objeto "p", de tipo Persona, este objeto p, tendrá varios atributos, digamos nombre y edad, podría convertir a string cada atributo si, pero hasta donde se, el objeto p, tal cual como objeto, no.